# get scrollTop, get offsetHeight and getStyle are taking a long time

Tags: javascript, performance, extjs, rally

The top three operations that are killing my performance are:

- get scrollTop
- get offsetHeight
- Ext.getStyle

To explain whats going on in my app: I have a grid, with a column that renders grids in each cell. It runs slow when I pretty much do anything to the grid's contents, like adding rows, or adding rows to the nested grids.

I don't know how to optimize these 3 calls, and I've googled a lot for this issue. Can anyone explain why getting styles is so expensive?

[image]

Comment: Try suspend and resuming  the grid events once.Using grid.suspendEvents() and grid.resumeEvents() it might help you.

Comment: Thanks, however I do currently have the store events suspended, and I'm also calling record.beginEdit() and record.endEdit() if im making bulk record changes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One optimization that should help, is to only grab the values when the browser is repainted. Briefly, here's how the javascript event loop works: When a function is entered, it has control of the CPU until the function ends. If another event occurs (like a window resize, an ajax request completing, or a button clicked), that event is pushed onto the Event Queue. When a function is completed and the CPU is free, then the Event Queue pops one thing off of the queue and gives the CPU to it.

One part of the execution loop is the "Animation Frame" part. You can set up some code to run before the next repaint. Here is some documentation: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/window.requestAnimationFrame

How this can help you:

When the user does the action that is slow, create a throttled function and put it into the requestAnimationFrame callback. Like this:

```
var rafCallback = function() {
  doComputationallyExpensiveThings();
  rafCallbackEnabled = false;
};
var rafCallbackEnabled = false;
document.on('user does a thing', function() {
  if (rafCallbackEnabled) return;
  rafCallbackEnabled = true;
  window.requestAnimationFrame(rafCallback);
});
```

This will make your computationally expensive code run at most once per animation frame.

Comment: From your code it looks you are trying to throttle the expensive thing. But I only run the expensive thing 1 time on the click of a button and the user is unable to click on the button again until it is completely done.

But regarding your first sentance, I don't know how to wait until the repaint is finished to have extjs redo the layout